# Api call using fetch with method get

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I have to set an header in api call. My POST API calls are working fine. But in my get api calls, header is not getting set.

```
return fetch('http://api-call.com', {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {
    Accept: 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'custom-security':'XXXX',
    'Purchase-Code':'XXXXXXX',
    'Content-Type':'application/json',
    'Cache-Control':'max-age=640000'
  }
})
.then((response) => response.json())
.then((responseJson) => {
  console.log(responseJson);
})
.catch((error) => {
  console.error(error);
});
```

Comment: add code snippet

Comment: And write a properly detailed problem description. Details provided are far too vague. Take a few minutes to read [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: @BugHunter - Edited my question..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should setup a `Request` object and pass your headers wrapped into a  `Headers` object, like:

```
var request = new Request('http://api-call.com', {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: new Headers({
       'Accept': 'application/json',
       'custom-security':'XXXX',
       'Purchase-Code':'XXXXXXX',
       'Content-Type':'application/json',
       'Cache-Control':'max-age=640000'
    })
});
```

Then just invoke fetch with your `request` as parameter:

```
fetch(request)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {
        console.log(responseJson);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
    });
```

Check [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/API/Headers)

Answer (score 1):

2021 answer: just in case you land here looking for how to make GET and POST Fetch api requests using async/await or promises as compared to axios.

I'm using jsonplaceholder fake API to demonstrate:

Fetch api GET request using async/await:

```
         const asyncGetCall = async () => {
            try {
                const response = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts');
                 const data = await response.json();
                // enter you logic when the fetch is successful
                 console.log(data);
               } catch(error) {
            // enter your logic for when there is an error (ex. error toast)
                  console.log(error)
                 } 
            }


          asyncGetCall()
```

Fetch api POST request using async/await:

```
    const asyncPostCall = async () => {
            try {
                const response = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts', {
                 method: 'POST',
                 headers: {
                   'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                   },
                   body: JSON.stringify({
             // your expected POST request payload goes here
                     title: "My post title",
                     body: "My post content."
                    })
                 });
                 const data = await response.json();
              // enter you logic when the fetch is successful
                 console.log(data);
               } catch(error) {
             // enter your logic for when there is an error (ex. error toast)

                  console.log(error)
                 } 
            }

asyncPostCall()
```

GET request using Promises:

```
  fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(data => {
   // enter you logic when the fetch is successful
    console.log(data)
  })
  .catch(error => {
    // enter your logic for when there is an error (ex. error toast)
   console.log(error)
  })
```

POST request using Promises:

```
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
   body: JSON.stringify({
     // your expected POST request payload goes here
      title: "My post title",
      body: "My post content."
      })
})
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(data => {
   // enter you logic when the fetch is successful
    console.log(data)
  })
  .catch(error => {
  // enter your logic for when there is an error (ex. error toast)
   console.log(error)
  })
```

GET request using Axios:

```
        const axiosGetCall = async () => {
            try {
              const { data } = await axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
    // enter you logic when the fetch is successful
              console.log(`data: `, data)
           
            } catch (error) {
    // enter your logic for when there is an error (ex. error toast)
              console.log(`error: `, error)
            }
          }
    
    axiosGetCall()
```

Authenticated POST request using Axios:

```
const axiosPostCall = async () => {
    try {
      const { data } = await axios.post('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts',  {
      // your expected POST request payload goes here
      title: "My post title",
      body: "My post content."
      },{
          headers: {
               Authorization:
            `Bearer ${token}`
          }
         })
   // enter you logic when the fetch is successful
      console.log(`data: `, data)
   
    } catch (error) {
  // enter your logic for when there is an error (ex. error toast)
      console.log(`error: `, error)
    }
  }


axiosPostCall()
```